How to compare clusters from different years?
I have multiple data sets, all organized similarly (same variables, values, etc.). I've independently analyzed the data sets using KModes, however, I was trying to look for trends that might occur over the years. How would I go about comparing the clusters from different years?

You could start with averaging the features for each cluster, and then plotting the average of a feature at different points in time. That will give a simple aggregate view of overall temporal trends. There are ways of drilling down into the clustering structure. Consider posting this question on the DataScience StackExchange, which is more suited to this type of question. @ethqnol
